# Selecting all words inside curly brackets to paste into a new file with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, selection

I have a dictionary document that uses the following syntax:

```
\lem{WORD}{POS}{PL}{DEFINITION}

\lem{WORD}{POS}{PL}{DEFINITION}

\lem{WORD}{POS}{PL}{DEFINITION}

and etc..
```

I want to select every `WORD` and copy-paste it into a new file.

Using the find function with the regular expression of `\\lem\{\w+\}` I can highlight all the words I need (and I could easily delete the fluff), however I can't figure out how to *select them*.

Is this possible? If not, is there some other program I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the **Python Script** plugin into NP++ and the python interpreter for win (https://www.python.org/downloads/ , I use v2.7.11). Don't forget to allow the installer to append the directory of **python.exe** to the PATH.

Then selecting Plugins->Python Script->New script, you you have to type some name of the script's code. I used **cplemname** for this code:

```
from Npp import *
import re

content = editor.getText()
temp=""

matches = re.findall( '\\lem{(\w+)}', content)

for m in matches:
    temp += m + "\n"

editor.copyText( temp)
```

Then inside the tab that your definitions are, just select Plugins->Python Script->Scripts->cplemname. Your words should be the content of the clipboard at this point, ready to be pasted.

Comment: I've done the above and this appears to crash Npp.

Comment: Mine is v6.8.8 and does it well.

Comment: Turns out the plugin, `DSpellCheck` must have been causing a conflict, after uninstalling that your solution worked.